# Split on a dash in python

Tags: python, fme-form, splitting

SO I am looking to do a split on a attribute that looks like 45-4.  Now all the attributes have values.

here is my code so far:

```
import fme
import fmeobjects

def processFeature(feature):

    f_type = feature.getAttribute('F_TYP')
    if f_type:
        f_type.split('-')
        Height = f_type[0]
        Class = f_type[-1]

        feature.setAttribute("Height", Height)
        feature.setAttribute("Class", Class)
```

It seems to work but only gives me as an example the height = 4 and the class 4.  I guess I need to take everything in front of the dash when it exists for height and everything after the dash for class.  I do need the if statement to deal with no values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you're not storing the result of the `.split()` anywhere. Secondly, the statements which allocate values to Height and Class are actually assigning the first and last characters of the attribute string respectively (which is why your example of '**4**5-**4**' results in Height and Class both being 4), rather than the two components you want. Using the code below, you should get the expected result:

```
import fme
import fmeobjects

def processFeature(feature):

f_type = feature.getAttribute('F_TYP')
if f_type:
    f_type_parts = f_type.split('-')
    Height = f_type_parts[0]
    Class = f_type_parts[-1]

    feature.setAttribute("Height", Height)
    feature.setAttribute("Class", Class)
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `f_type_parts = f_type.split('-')` statement, and change the assignments for Height and Class as follows:

```
Height = f_type.split('-')[0]
Class = f_type.split('-')[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that small change you talked about and it worked perfect.  I am trying to learn Python because of how much easier it is to use for tasks like this.

Comment: No worries. I'm learning too,  it's good fun!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in FME, I'd suggest using the AttributeSplitter with - as the delimiter. Then right click on the resulting _list{} attribute shown on the AttributeSplitter OUTPUT port on the canvas, and Expose 2 elements. After that, use an AttributeRenamer to rename _list{0} to Height and _list{1} to Class.

Comment: how does that work with attributes with no value or mislabeled ones that do not have the dash to split them?

Comment: You could do  ListElementCounter after the AttributeSplitter to get the number of values it split into, and then use a Tester after that to discard/complain about the ones that didn't get 2 values extracted.